# Inconsistency in definition of STL upper_bound?

Tags: c++, stl

The [documentation for upper_bound](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/upper_bound.html) states:

> ...it attempts to find the element value in an ordered range [first, last)... upper_bound returns the furthermost iterator i in [first, last) such that, for every iterator j in [first, i), value < *j is false.

However, if we have a `vector<int> v` that contains the numbers 1, 2, and 3, calling `upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 5)` will return `v.end()`. But based on the definition, `v.end()` is not in the range `[v.begin, v.end())`. There is no such iterator that fits the requirements in the definition. Is the definition just lazy in not explicitly stating what happens in this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SGI documentation is not relevant – the *C++ standard* is what you should be reading. Quoting C++11 §25.4.3.2:

> *Returns:* The furthermost iterator `i` in the range `[first,last]` such that for any iterator `j` in the range `[first,i)` the following corresponding conditions hold: `!(value < *j)` or `comp(value, *j) == false`.

Comment: @PlasmaHH : Fair point, but I've never see anyone really mean the SGI STL, so I'm going under the assumption that the OP was referring to the standard library algorithm.

Comment: My issue was with the wording in the SGI STL, but my confusion is cleared up now that I see the c++ standard is unambiguous. Lesson learned: consult the standard, not SGI.

Comment: @ildjarn: You are just not old enough then ;)